# Counting 2 tables on the same rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, count

I want to count 2 tables with different structure, but 1 row is the same:

```
T1 = id_title
T2 = id_title
```

id_title can be 1-10 (categories) for both tables (it's dependent on each other) and I need to count exact rows for each T1+T2 id_title..

example:

```
id_title | count
    1    |   4 (T1+T2 id_title)
    2    |   6 (T1+T2 id_title)
    3    |   2 (T1+T2 id_title)
```

and so on..

Then order it by highest (count) to lowest.. is it possible in SQL query or I must figure out in PHP with loop or something ?

Comment: SELECT id_title, COUNT(*) ttl FROM (SELECT id_title FROM t1 UNION ALL SELECT id_title FROM t2)x GROUP BY id_title;

Comment: yeah, this works, but is there a chance how to include rows with NULL result ?

Comment: Eh? What do you mean? Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle - we should make it a prerequisite of any SQL question asked on SO) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: nevermind, your SQL query you send, it's working perfect.. I'm sorry, it's maybe better when it's not shown in results while doesn't exist in T1 or T2..

Comment: if you are worried about nulls what I do sometimes is add a condition `where isnull(fieldname,'') <> ''`

But it sounds like you have it under control.

Comment: this condition don't work, because of that issue "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull'". I can't tell, I have this under control, but it's working and if someone create this title, it will be displayed, so, what's the harm, if not displayed while doesn't exist..